# Apple camera permission not being asked - iPad Air 9.3.5

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

We currently have an application for iOS that needs to use camera to record videos.

Our app is an enterprise app used internally and they are distributed by [airWatch](http://www.air-watch.com/). During our tests we discovered a strange behaviour in some devices. Currently we have a number close to 900 devices with our application, most of them are iPad Air devices and when the camera is required, an alert is presented to the user to activate the camera permission.

We have 2 different behaviours following the same steps on different devices with the same configuration.

> Case 1 - The user needs to use the camera, then an alert appear to the
> user saying that the app needs to use the camera. You select yes to
> activate the camera and can use the application.
>
> Case 2 - We have around 30 device that have this problem, the alert
> presented to the user says that they don't have camera permission and
> they need to activate it on Settings. The user is redirected to the
> Settings but we can't find our application in the list to activate the
> camera and it does not appear in Settings -> Privacy -> Camera. Since
> the user can't use the camera, the app cannot be used for its purpose.

I know that the resource permission only appear after the permission is asked at least once, but following the same steps after a new installation produces different results in 2 devices with the same configuration.

Is there any reason for this to happen only in some devices? All of them have the same version of the app.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably those devices are running `iOS10`. Since `iOS10` you should provide the description why you are asking for the permission, if not the app could crash or not display the permission request alertView.

Some keys you should add to your `Info.plist` to access Camera & Photo Library:

```
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
NSCameraUsageDescription
```

Some of the keys with examples of description:

[image]
[Source](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html)

Comment: Hi @Pau Senabre , we already made those changes for iOS 10. Using airWatch we can verify which iOS version the final user has installed on his device